# Cannot resolve keyword 'average_rating' into field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my models and views file.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    
    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return self.articlecomments.all().aggregate(Avg('rate')).get('rate__avg', 0.00)

class ArticleComment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='articleratings')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='articleratings_author')
    rate = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

```
class ArticleByCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-average_rating')
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

What I try to do is sort the articles by its rating but it does not work. It gives me this error:

```
raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'average_rating' into field. Choices are:......
```

I used it as a property.How can I solve this problem?Is there an alternative way?

Comment: `average_rating` is a property, not a database field. Hence, you can't use it in `order_by`.

Comment: any alternatives @xyres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't order by property, because this field does not exists in database.

Annotate this field first and then use `order_by`.

Try this:

```
queryset = Article.objects.annotate(
    average_rating=Avg('articlecomments__rate', default=0)
).order_by('-average_rating')
```

Edit: Added logic to return 0 value as default